# Initial route params in React Navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

React Navigation v3 was featuring an *initialRouteParams* property to pass initial values to *this.navigation.props*. Is there a way to set initial route params to be accessed via *route.params* in the React Navigation v5?

```
function MainScreen({route, navigation}) {
    return (
        // how to pass default values to route in here?
        // route.params.userParam ?
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It could be accomplished by passing *[initialParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)* to the *Stack.Screen*:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Main"
    component={MainScreen}
    initialParams={{ /* initialParams */ }}
/>
```

There is also a handy default syntax one can use (see [No more getParam](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html#no-more-getparam)):

```
route.params?.userParam ?? 'defaultValue'
```

Comment: This does not seem to work when the "Main" screen is actually another Stack.Navigator. Then the params are not passed to the Screen rendered in this navigator.

Comment: Of great help thanks.