# How to pass a function to update state in Navigation Screen Component - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm fairly new to React Native and I have created a Drawer Navigator in my App.js file.

One of my navigation components is named LifeScreen.

I am trying to pass a function to update a state (setSavedQuotes) to LifeScreen so that in LifeScreen I can update the value of the state (savedQuotes). This is straightforward in React but I can't seem to be able to do the same in React Native.

**App.js (Navigator)**

```
const App = () => {
    const [savedQuotes, setSavedQuotes] = useState([])

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="Home" 
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    initialParams={{ sam: savedQuotes }}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="Life"
                    component={props => {
                        return <LifeScreen props={props} setSavedQuotes={setSavedQuotes} />
                    }}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Work" component={WorkScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Saved" component={SavedScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

**LifeScreen.js**

```
const LifeScreen = ({ route, setSavedQuotes }) => {
    const [quote, setQuote] = useState('')

    const lifeWisdom = [...] // array of quotes
    const getQuote = () => {... } // get Random Quote

    const saveQuote = () => {
        // console.log('life:', route.params)
        console.log("function: ", setSavedQuotes);  // returns undefined
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={getQuote} style={styles.quoteContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.quote}>{quote}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveQuote} style={styles.imgContainer}>
                <AntDesign name="hearto" size={40} color="black" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Whenever I console.log(setSavedQuotes), I get undefined.

I can pass props and the state value without any problem, as I did with HomeSCreen in App.js.
I tried the following: [regarding props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688531/how-do-i-pass-a-prop-to-a-navigation-screen-component-react-native), [initialParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60115818/initial-route-params-in-react-navigation-v5), [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8517) and route. I can manage to pass the state with all of them, but not the function to update the state.

Comment: try this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114496/passing-function-as-a-param-in-react-navigation-5

Comment: @WenW Using that answer and the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/) I can pass values back to another Screen and update the value of my hook there. It can be a solution. 
As a side effect, it brings me to that Screen.

Comment: awesome, i'm glad you found a solution. :)